# With Devise, how do I force the redirect location after sign in?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm using this line after authenticating with Omniauth:

```
sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication
```

But in that particular case, I want to change the redirect location, regardless of any stored location.

Something like:

```
sign_in_and_redirect(@user, :event => :authentication, :redirect_to => '/settings')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could over ride your after_sign_in_path in that controller as follows:

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController

private

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    if resource.is_a?(User)
       WHEREVER YOU WANT TO REDIRECT THEM
    end
  end
end
```